# How to interpret response from vt-100 / vt-102 DA request

Tags: python, curses, terminal-emulator, ansi-escape

How should the response from the DA escape sequence (`\e[c`) be interpreted?

When running the command in urxvt i get `1;2`, in linux console (and st) i get `6;` and in xterm i get `64;1;2;6;9;15;18;21;22`.

From what I have been able to find on the internet these strings are supposed to somehow identify the terminals capabilities. http://www.vt100.net/docs/vt100-ug/chapter3.html#DA

```
No options                  ESC [?1;0c
Processor option (STP)      ESC [?1;1c
Advanced video option (AVO) ESC [?1;2c
AVO and STP                 ESC [?1;3c
Graphics option (GPO)       ESC [?1;4c
GPO and STP                 ESC [?1;5c
GPO and AVO                 ESC [?1;6c
GPO, STP and AVO            ESC [?1;7c
```

This seems to fit with the response from urxvt (and possibly xterm) but not with the others. All the mentioned terminals seems to be fairly VT-102 compatible and as far as I know that would map to 1;2 (AVO).

Anyone out there who knows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

documentation for the xterm response is readily found in [*XTerm Control Sequences*](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h4-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character-lparen-s-rparen:CSI-Ps-c.1CA3)

note as with all X window apps there is a resource to change the response to whatever you want..

```
       
CSI Ps c  Send Device Attributes (Primary DA).
            Ps = 0  or omitted ⇒  request attributes from terminal.  The
          response depends on the decTerminalID resource setting.
            ⇒  CSI ? 1 ; 2 c  ("VT100 with Advanced Video Option")
            ⇒  CSI ? 1 ; 0 c  ("VT101 with No Options")
            ⇒  CSI ? 6 c  ("VT102")
            ⇒  CSI ? 6 2 ; Psc  ("VT220")
            ⇒  CSI ? 6 3 ; Psc  ("VT320")
            ⇒  CSI ? 6 4 ; Psc  ("VT420")

          The VT100-style response parameters do not mean anything by
          themselves.  VT220 (and higher) parameters do, telling the
          host what features the terminal supports:
            Ps = 1  ⇒  132-columns.
            Ps = 2  ⇒  Printer.
            Ps = 3  ⇒  ReGIS graphics.
            Ps = 4  ⇒  Sixel graphics.
            Ps = 6  ⇒  Selective erase.
            Ps = 8  ⇒  User-defined keys.
            Ps = 9  ⇒  National Replacement Character sets.
            Ps = 1 5  ⇒  Technical characters.
            Ps = 1 6  ⇒  Locator port.
            Ps = 1 7  ⇒  Terminal state interrogation.
            Ps = 1 8  ⇒  User windows.
            Ps = 2 1  ⇒  Horizontal scrolling.
            Ps = 2 2  ⇒  ANSI color, e.g., VT525.
            Ps = 2 8  ⇒  Rectangular editing.
            Ps = 2 9  ⇒  ANSI text locator (i.e., DEC Locator mode).
xt locator (i.e., DEC Locator mode)
```

my WAG some emulators don't implement this completely/correctly so if you depend on it you need to go on a case by case basis.

Comment: Any idea what the primary source for this information is?  (i. e. is there some DEC document that describes it?)

Answer (score 1):

According to [VT100.net](http://www.vt100.net/docs/vt420-uu/chapter9.html#T9-1), 64 appears to designate VT-420 capabilities:

> VT420 DA* CSI ? 64; 1; 2; 6; 7; 8; 9; 15; 18; 19; 21 c    VT420 terminal

But as [george](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18380004/282912) noted, and having hacked a few termcap entries back in the day, there is very little consistency in even what a single terminal type will answer in reply to inquiries.

There's a ton of information at that site, all of which should be considered "best effort" by the authors as "authoritative" really cannot be achieved.

Comment: +1 for the link.  Gave me flash backs to using fortran to drive vt240  four color graphics with all those nasty escape codes...